# How to create Image file in libGDX from pixel array

Tags: java, libgdx

I stuck in one point where I have to create image file(the best would be PNG) from pixel array where the array, width and height are given as parameters. The real problem is that i can't use `BufferedImage` or `ImageIO`.

Implementation of this is already implemented in Android subproject using Bitmap like this:

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pixels,
                width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

Pixel map is created by merging 3 images color informations.

Without using `BufferedImage` or `ImageIO` I have no idea how to deal with it.

Do u have any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Pixmap](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/ci/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.html#Pixmap-byte:A-int-int-):

```
Pixmap pixmap = new Pixmap(pixels, 0, pixels.length);
Texture texture = new Texture(pixmap);
```

Comment: Ok, I've achieved this thanks to you by creating `FileHandle` to new file and get PNG by `PixmapIO`. Many thanks.